# How is one of the steps in the policy gradient theorem done?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, reinforcement-learning

In page 269 of [the latest draft of Richard S. Sutton's RL book](http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf), he proves the policy gradient theorem for episodic MDPs. I'm trying to follow the proof, but I don't understand one of the steps. How does he go from:

$$ \sum_a \left[\nabla\pi(a|s)q_\pi(s,a)+\pi(a|s)\sum_{s'}p(s'|s,a)\sum_{a'}[\nabla\pi(a'|s')q_\pi(s',a')+\pi(a'|s')\sum_{s''}p(s''|s',a')\nabla v_\pi(s'')] \right] $$

to:

$$ \sum_{r\in \mathcal{S}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty Pr(s\rightarrow x,k,\pi)\sum_a \nabla \pi(a|x)q_\pi(x,a) ~?$$

He mentions that this is obtained after "repeated unrolling", where "unrolling" means (judging from the previous step in the proof) expanding $v_\pi(x)$ into its definition, dependent on $v_\pi(x')$.

Can anyone help me clarify this step?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the book, $Pr(s\rightarrow x,k,\pi)$ is the probability of transitioning from state s to state x in k steps. So $$Pr(s\rightarrow x,0,\pi)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1  & \mbox{if } x = s \\0 & \mbox{otherwise} \end{array}\right.$$
$$Pr(s\rightarrow x,1,\pi)=\sum_a\pi(a|s)p(x|s,a)$$ $$Pr(s\rightarrow x,2,\pi)=\sum_a\pi(a|s)\sum_{s'}p(s'|s,a)\sum_{a'}\pi(a'|s')p(x|s',a')$$.
Then the above result can be derived by expanding (unrolling) and rewriting.
$$ \nabla v_\pi(s) = \sum_a [\nabla\pi(a|s)q_\pi(s,a)+\pi(a|s)\sum_{s'}p(s'|s,a)\nabla v_\pi(s')] $$
$$ = \sum_a \left[\nabla\pi(a|s)q_\pi(s,a)+\pi(a|s)\sum_{s'}p(s'|s,a)\sum_{a'}[\nabla\pi(a'|s')q_\pi(s',a')+\pi(a'|s')\sum_{s''}p(s''|s',a')\nabla v_\pi(s'')] \right] $$
$$ = \sum_a \nabla\pi(a|s)q_\pi(s,a)+\sum_a\pi(a|s)\sum_{s'}p(s'|s,a)\sum_{a'}\nabla\pi(a'|s')q_\pi(s',a')+\sum_a\pi(a|s)\sum_{s'}p(s'|s,a)\sum_{a'}\pi(a'|s')\sum_{s''}p(s''|s',a')\nabla v_\pi(s'')$$
$$ = \sum_{x\in \mathcal{S}}Pr(s\rightarrow x,0,\pi)\sum_a \nabla\pi(a|s)q_\pi(s,a)+\sum_{x\in \mathcal{S}}Pr(s\rightarrow x,1,\pi)\sum_{a'}\nabla\pi(a'|s')q_\pi(s',a')+\sum_{x\in \mathcal{S}}Pr(s\rightarrow x,2,\pi)\nabla v_\pi(s'')$$
repeatedly unrolling $\nabla v_\pi(s'')$ we get
$$ \sum_{x\in \mathcal{S}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty Pr(s\rightarrow x,k,\pi)\sum_a \nabla \pi(a|x)q_\pi(x,a)$$